# Test case automation

Tags: automation

I am new to test automation and I need help of experts who can help me in proceeding with the current difficulties.
Currently there is a web browser application which is tested manually based on the test cases in an excel.

There is also an automation framework also which uses Selenium and uses WebDriver and runs on Google Chrome.

The test cases(in excel) used for manual are taken up and another set of test cases(in excel) are written which is nothing but the div elements and the action which the framework should do like click or find which the framework will understand.

1.First I need to manually find out each div id for all the elements and put it in excel which the framework understands.**How can I avoid this?**

2.Also a new version of the application has come in which all the div id for the elements differ.Hence its pain to note the div id again and put them in excel.
**How can I write the test cases only once for each case even if the div changes?**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a design pattern, e.g. [Page Objects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

Comment: How about using Selenium IDE to record the test case and then export it to WebDriver code in c#.Are there any issues using it?

Comment: Yes.  Selenium IDE will not provide a stable, mature, maintainable and reliable test suite

Answer (score 0):

If ids will be changed try to use css and xpath selectors that do not stick to ids. The main idea is to specify such selectors that allow tests to find elements on the page using knowledge by their parents, tag names, other attributes that won't change (class and so on).